# Office.js Dialog closes immediately after being shown (Excel Online)

Tags: office-js

I am implementing dialog for Excel add-in. Everything works great on desktop version. But when hosted at Office Online dialog closes immediately after being shown.

When I remove Office.initialize assignation from dialog page - it shows correctly. But simply adding this script causes dialog closing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    };
</script>
```

The bug persists only when displayInIframe: true is used.

The whole dialog markup used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>
    <!-- Template styles -->
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body class="ms-font-m">
    <div class="page dialog-external">
    </div>
    <div class="k-loading-mask">
        <div class="k-loading-color"></div>
        <div class="k-loading-image"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
        Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Calling code:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + "/dialog.html?v=1.0.0.0&" + common.getQueryString(options), {
        width: 40,
        height: 50,
        displayInIframe: true
    }, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
            showInternalDialog(options);
        }
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
    });
```

Comment: What is the URL you are passing to displayDialogAsync? Could it be a page that doesn't support opening in an IFrame? Is it a page with the same domain as the host page? That's a requirement.

Comment: The page is extremely simple and hosted on the same domain as the main page.

Comment: Does the dialog.html page redirect to another page?

Comment: No it doesn't. I simplified the dialog, so
Office.initialize = function (reason) {}; 
is the only custom script apart
https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js

Comment: I'm researching. In the meantime, what browser and OS are you seeing this on? Does happen on other browsers?

Comment: I've tested it in Win10 on the latest Chrome, IE, FX - all the same. I'll test it on Edge & Safari soon. But it seems browser independent.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Office product team has reproduced this. It is a new bug that we are working on. In the meantime, the workaround is to not set `displayInIframe` to `true`.

**UPDATE:** As Michael Z indicates in his comment. The bug has been fixed. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: FYI:  the issue has now been fixed.  If you encounter further issues, please open them as bugs on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues